# updating centroids in k-means Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, k-means

I'm implementing the K means algorithm in python and I got stuck in
 the part in which we suppose to update the centroids.
I have created something that works but its really not python-like.
I know it can be written better and would love for some suggestions
for example how to improve the histogram that counts how many points
are assigned to each centroid.

Here is my code:

```
def updateCentroids(centroids, pixelList):
    k = len(centroids)
    centoidsCount = [0]*k #couts how many pixels classified for each cent.
    centroidsSum = np.zeros([k, 3])#sum value of centroids
    for pixel in pixelList:
        index = 0
        #find whitch centroid equals
        for centroid in centroids:
            if np.array_equal(pixel.classification, centroid):
                centoidsCount[index] += 1
                centroidsSum[index] += pixel.point
                break
            index += 1
    index = 0
    for centroid in centroidsSum:
        centroids[index] = centroid/centoidsCount[index]
        index += 1
```